# How to execute a file from URL

Tags: xss, demo

I'm writing a demo for a file upload attack. I have uploaded my file to the server. How can I execute the file I just uploaded from the URL like a hacker

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wvba7.png)

Comment: If you are uploading code, please use it using the `code` formatter.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].